# How to show devider in listview when there is only single item present

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listview but it only shows devider between two items , i have a case where i have to show devider when there is only single item present or only few items are present that do not fill the whole page , In such case no devider appears on last item that  & looks weird.
Footerview can not help as deviders images are indiapendant from phone to phone .
Can any one help ?

Comment: You can add that Devider along with the listView Item, How is that ?

Answer (score 1):

you can add view after ListView like this :

```
<Listview....../>
 <View
        android:id="@+id/invisible"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a transparent footer at the end of `ListView` using `addFooterView(someTransparentView, null, true);` Make sure you have `android:footerDividersEnabled` set to true. This way android will draw divider before footer.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a border for the whole ListView so that it doesn't look so weird.Here is an example to explain this:

```
    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/profile_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:divider="#C0C0C0"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:background="@drawable/custombox"
  ></ListView>
```

We set the ListView background to a custom xml that is placed within drawable/ folder. In the above case custombox.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <gradient android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:centerColor="#FFFFFF" android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:angle="270" android:centerX="0.5" android:centerY="0.5" />
      <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#C0C0C0" />
      <corners android:radius="0dp" />
      <padding android:left="3dp" android:top="3dp" android:right="3dp"
        android:bottom="3dp" />
    </shape>
  </item>
  </selector>
```

Here we set the shape of the entire ListView and stroke is the border which is set to a width of 1dp and color #C0C0C0.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to [setFooterDividersEnabled(true)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setFooterDividersEnabled%28boolean%29) without a footer view in your list?